# Clustered puma not accepting more than 1 request concurrently

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, puma, mri

I have setup my puma web server based on heroku manual: [Deploying Rails Applications with the Puma Web Server](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-rails-applications-with-the-puma-web-server)

`config/puma.rb`:

```
workers Integer(ENV['WEB_CONCURRENCY'] || 2)
threads_count = Integer(ENV['RAILS_MAX_THREADS'] || 2)
threads threads_count, threads_count

preload_app!

rackup      DefaultRackup
port        ENV['PORT']     || 3000
environment ENV['RACK_ENV'] || 'development'

on_worker_boot do
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
end
```

`Procfile` contains:

```
web: bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb
```

Now when I try to access action which has `sleep 10` which delays the response and then try to access some other action, my understanding was that Puma would handle these 2 requests concurrently (since I have 2 workers). But instead it waits for the first request which sleeps to finish then it proceeds to the second one. Am i missing something?

My setup is:

- Ruby 2.2.4
- Rails 4.2.0

**EDIT:**

Ok, so I found out that on Heroku, it works, so question is, why it doesn't work in development mode?

Comment: How are you running the server in development?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rails s` does not use the Procfile, you may want to look at using a tool like foreman: https://github.com/ddollar/foreman

update: this was the solution:

`config.allow_concurrency = true` in the rails development config.

Comment: That's odd because from what I've seen in logs when starting server it seems like Puma has started in exactly what configuration I've set up.

Comment: So even when i booted server with Foreman, this still does not work.

Comment: @MartinSvoboda try `config.allow_concurrency=true` in your `config/development.rb`

Comment: So there is another issue with this. When i set `allow_concurrency = true`, the development log in terminal shows only for first request then it seems not to register any requests.

Comment: @MartinSvoboda Try tailing log/development.log. I'm assuming all output is in there. concurrency isn't used in development so some typical dev tools may not work quite as expected (e.g. pry)